# What does "You thought I was out of your league" mean in the lyrics of Next to You by Jordin Sparks?

Tags: meaning-in-context

### I asked around and I heard that you were talking
Told my girl that you thought **I was out of your league** What a fool, I got to get next to you

Does the girl, who represents the speaker, is too good for the guy, or the other way around?

Definition:
To say that someone is “out of your league” means that someone else (or something else) that you want to date or have some kind of connection with is smarter than you, better-looking than you, younger than you, makes more money than you, is of a higher social class than you, or is more advanced in their careers than you, or any combination of the above. Basically, it refers to a giant gap between you and this other person or thing you want.

Answer (score 1):

From The Free Dictionary:

> **[out of (one's) league](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+(one%27s)+league)**: Not the proper match for someone, often because the other person is considered superior in some way. Although it can be used in other situations, this phrase is very often applied to romantic partners who are more attractive or wealthy.

Let's call the singer *Girl 1*.

> I asked around and I heard that you were talking --> *Girl 1* is saying that she's heard that the boy she's attracted to has been talking.

> Told my girl that you thought I was out of your league --> *Girl 1* is saying she heard that the boy told the girl's friend, *Girl 2* (a.k.a. "my girl"), that he thought *Girl 1* was **out of his league**.

> What a fool, I got to get next to you --> *Girl 1* is saying that the boy is a fool for thinking she (*Girl 1*) is out of his league ... and that she needs to "get next to him". Wink, wink.

Answer (score 0):

The speaker is saying that they heard from "my girl" that "you" thought the speaker was out of your league - so if the girl is the speaker and the guy is you, the guy thought the girl was too good for him. But the girl seems to not agree (calling him a fool).

Answer (score 0):

*My girl* is Jordin's female friend.

Jordin's friend heard the man talking. The man was saying  that he wished to date Jordin but he thought that Jordin was too good/pretty etc. for him.

However he doesn't realise that Jordin likes him too. Jordin has been dreaming about him
and would like to date him (she wants to get next to him), she says he is a fool for not trying to speak to her.

She says she wants to get next to him (get into a relationship).